# Android Studio 2.3 on Windows 10 wait forever on first gradle build

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I update Android studio to release 2.3 on Windows 10 with JDK 1.8.121. When i try to create a new project, Android studio start to wait foreverer with this screen. Note this happens when i try to open already existing projects too.

[image]

Is anybody with my same problem?

The Android Studio logs are:

```
2017-03-04 13:20:27,045 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2017-03-04 13:20:27,076 [     31]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: Android Studio (build #AI-162.3764568, 24 Feb 2017 00:00) 
2017-03-04 13:20:27,076 [     31]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 10 (10.0, amd64) 
2017-03-04 13:20:27,076 [     31]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b06 (JetBrains s.r.o) 
2017-03-04 13:20:27,076 [     31]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.112-b06 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
2017-03-04 13:20:27,078 [     33]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms256m -Xmx1280m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -da -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -Djna.debug_load=true -Djna.debug_load.jna=true -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio2.3 -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Didea.jre.check=true -Djb.vmOptionsFile=C:\MyProgramFiles\AndroidStudio\bin\studio64.exe.vmoptions -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\MyProgramFiles\AndroidStudio\lib\boot.jar -Didea.jre.check=false -XX:ErrorFile=C:\Users\xcesco\java_error_in___product_uc___%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\xcesco\java_error_in___product_uc__.hprof 
2017-03-04 13:20:27,078 [     33]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ext: C:\MyProgramFiles\AndroidStudio\jre\jre\lib\ext: [access-bridge-64.jar, cldrdata.jar, dnsns.jar, jaccess.jar, localedata.jar, meta-index, nashorn.jar, sunec.jar, sunjce_provider.jar, sunmscapi.jar, sunpkcs11.jar, zipfs.jar] 
2017-03-04 13:20:27,078 [     33]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNU charset: Cp1252 
2017-03-04 13:20:27,109 [     64]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library loaded (64-bit) in 31 ms 
2017-03-04 13:20:27,111 [     66]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
2017-03-04 13:20:27,112 [     67]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - Using "FocusKiller" library to prevent focus stealing. 
2017-03-04 13:20:27,135 [     90]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI - UI scale factor: 1.0 
2017-03-04 13:20:27,626 [    581]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor duplicates-groovy.xml 
2017-03-04 13:20:27,965 [    920]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 35 plugins initialized in 547 ms 
2017-03-04 13:20:27,971 [    926]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: Android Games (1.0), Android NDK Support (1.0), Android Support (10.2.3), App Links Assistant (0.1), CVS Integration (11), Copyright (8.1), Coverage (162.2228.14), EditorConfig (162.2228.14), Firebase App Indexing (0.1), Firebase Services (0.1), Firebase Testing (1.0), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub (162.2228.14), Google Cloud Tools Core (0.2.8), Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio (0.2.8), Google Developers Samples (0.3.1), Google Login (1.0), Google Services (0.1), Gradle (162.2228.14), Groovy (9.0), I18n for Java (162.2228.14), IDEA CORE (162.2228.14), IntelliLang (8.0), JUnit (1.0), Java Bytecode Decompiler (162.2228.14), NDK WorkspaceManager Support (1.0), Properties Support (162.2228.14), Settings Repository (162.2228.14), Subversion Integration (1.1), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), Test Recorder (1.0), TestNG-J (8.0), YAML (162.2228.14), hg4idea (10.0) 
2017-03-04 13:20:29,480 [   2435]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=1217 
2017-03-04 13:20:29,508 [   2463]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: C:\MyProgramFiles\AndroidStudio\bin\fsnotifier64.exe 
2017-03-04 13:20:29,520 [   2475]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational. 
2017-03-04 13:20:29,883 [   2838]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI - UI scale factor changed: 1.0 
2017-03-04 13:20:30,126 [   3081]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
2017-03-04 13:20:30,151 [   3106]   INFO - gs.impl.UpdateCheckerComponent - channel: release 
2017-03-04 13:20:30,188 [   3143]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index exts enumerated:25 
2017-03-04 13:20:30,190 [   3145]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index scheduled:2 
2017-03-04 13:20:30,201 [   3156]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - All stub exts enumerated:6 
2017-03-04 13:20:30,202 [   3157]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - stub exts update scheduled:0 
2017-03-04 13:20:30,228 [   3183]   INFO - j.ide.script.IdeStartupScripts - 0 startup script(s) found 
2017-03-04 13:20:30,624 [   3579]   INFO - pl$FileIndexDataInitialization - Initialization done:434 
2017-03-04 13:20:30,673 [   3628]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 20 project components initialized in 339 ms 
2017-03-04 13:20:30,674 [   3629]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms 
2017-03-04 13:20:30,759 [   3714]   INFO - exImpl$StubIndexInitialization - Initialization done:134 
2017-03-04 13:20:31,855 [   4810]   INFO - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - 85 application components initialized in 4437 ms 
2017-03-04 13:20:31,868 [   4823]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 6375 ms 
2017-03-04 13:20:32,098 [   5053]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionPreloader@562cbd36 
2017-03-04 13:20:32,731 [   5686]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading file:/C:/MyProgramFiles/AndroidStudio/plugins/sdk-updates/offline-repo/offline-repo.xml 
2017-03-04 13:20:32,840 [   5795]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml 
2017-03-04 13:20:33,074 [   6029]   WARN - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - File C:\Users\xcesco\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded. 
2017-03-04 13:20:33,076 [   6031]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml 
2017-03-04 13:20:33,159 [   6114]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img2-1.xml 
2017-03-04 13:20:33,219 [   6174]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading com.intellij.ide.ui.search.SearchableOptionPreloader@4c4f7c8a 
2017-03-04 13:20:33,336 [   6291]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img2-1.xml 
2017-03-04 13:20:33,427 [   6382]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img2-1.xml 
2017-03-04 13:20:33,522 [   6477]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img2-1.xml 
2017-03-04 13:20:33,621 [   6576]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon2-1.xml 
2017-03-04 13:20:33,805 [   6760]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon2-1.xml 
2017-03-04 13:20:33,875 [   6830]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon2-1.xml 
2017-03-04 13:20:45,790 [  18745]   INFO - CompilerWorkspaceConfiguration - Available processors: 8 
2017-03-04 13:20:46,004 [  18959]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 138 project components initialized in 474 ms 
2017-03-04 13:20:46,005 [  18960]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms 
2017-03-04 13:20:47,131 [  20086]   INFO - i.vcs.changes.ChangeListWorker - default list not found when copy 
2017-03-04 13:20:47,131 [  20086]   INFO - i.vcs.changes.ChangeListWorker - default list not found when copy in original object too 
2017-03-04 13:20:47,248 [  20203]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Started sync with Gradle for project 'My Application'. 
2017-03-04 13:20:47,353 [  20308]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/MyProgramFiles/AndroidStudio/jre 
2017-03-04 13:20:47,366 [  20321]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/MyProgramFiles/AndroidStudio/jre 
2017-03-04 13:20:48,194 [  21149]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: [-Djava.awt.headless=true, -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true, -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.advanced=true, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, C:\Users\xcesco\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo3634.gradle, --init-script, C:\Users\xcesco\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit179.gradle]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours spent to try anything, the only solution that i found was to reinstall previous version 2.2.3 of Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for your problem. Basically it's cased by embedded android studio jdk the solution too simple just go to Project Structure->SDK Location-> unchecked Use embedded jdk and select the path to your stand-alone jdk
in my case (windows)

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
```

Comment: As i already write in other post, the only solution that i found was to wait next release of IDE. I'd try to use external JDK but result was the same